How can I prevent watermarks on an oiled kitchen worktop?
I have recently sanded my beech wood kitchen worktops down so I could re-oil them to freshen them up.
I applied clear Ronseal worktop oil after sanding.
I gave it 3 coats, 24 hours between each coat, and gave it a good 36 hours between the last coat and using the worktop to make sure it was bone dry.
The worktop not gets water marks really easily.
Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could do to prevent this?
I don’t really want to have to sand the whole thing down to use a different product if I can help it. I followed the instructions on precisely.

Oh this is easy, use a different finish!

I was writing my follow-up Answer to the above Comment when I noticed a key detail on the product page that may be relevant here. In point 5 of Application it says you need to refinish "when you see water smudging instead of beading or when the worktop has lost its sheen". So obviously water is supposed to bead up. Does your surface have a noticeable sheen and do you get water beading? If not something didn't go as intended.

Thanks! Yes the water is beading and it looks great, there's a nice sheen to it. Just a shame about the water marks for whatever reason

Can you describe the watermarks your getting in more detail, or, better, attach a couple of photos? Just need to check the problem is water getting through to the wood, rather than merely surface marking (which may be due to minerals in the water).

Sorry I don’t know how up upload photos, but basically, some water marks are white smudges (or circles if formed by the bottom of a bowl) and others are random darker patches which tbh I don’t actually know where they’ve come from.

Ah, it sounds like you're getting classic white marks. That's at least a step up from getting dark water stains that indicate water has gotten straight through to the wood. White marks are probably the most described water staining (with many fixes provided online, some of which work and some of which do not). Basically the cause is water getting through some of the finish and becoming trapped, and it indicates that a finish is inherently not resistant enough to water or one that has failed due to ageing.
